# Overwrite $_SESSION variable in php

Tags: php, session-variables

I have this code that is supposed to manage a form after submission and set the `$_SESSION` variable to a new value that is choiced from a select box by the user. The problem is that the default session variable will not be changed and if an user try to search it will obtain always the same results also if has changed the desired league. How i can solve this? NB: the `session_start()` is present in the index page who hold the code and also is present in the class file who manage the database operations.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'app/config.php';
require_once 'app/Autoloader.php';

$prediction = new Prediction(new DataManager($db));
$template = new TemplateLoader('app/templates/');

if(isset($_POST['search_matchday'])){
  $matchday = filter_var($_POST['matchday'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  $data = array(
   'data'=> $prediction->searchMatchday($matchday, $_SESSION['competition']),
   'date'=> new DateTime(),
   'results'=> $prediction->randomResult(),
   'logo'=> $prediction->competitionLogo($_SESSION['competition'])
  );

  echo $template->renderTemplate('home', $data);
}

if(isset($_POST['switch_competition'])){
   $competitionName = $_POST['competition'];
   $_SESSION['competition'] = $_POST['competition'];
   $data = array(
     'data'=> $prediction->switchCompetition($competitionName),
     'date'=> new DateTime(),
     'results'=> $prediction->randomResult(),
     'logo'=> $prediction->competitionLogo($competitionName)
    );

    echo $template->renderTemplate('home', $data);
}


$data = array(
  'data'=> $prediction->defaultCompetition(),
  'results'=> $prediction->randomResult(),
  'date'=> new DateTime(),
  'logo'=> $prediction->competitionLogo('Serie A')
);
$_SESSION['competition'] = 'Serie A';
echo $template->renderTemplate('home', $data);

?>
```

HTML form

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="">
  <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="matchday" id="input-matchday" placeholder="Cerca Giornata">
  <div class="input-group-append">
  <button type="submit" name="search_matchday" class="btn btn-link"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML form.

Comment: @Jeto form code added

Comment: So your PHP code can potentially call `$template->renderTemplate` three times? That seems... odd. Why is there a `$_SESSION['competition'] = 'Serie A';` before the third one?

Comment: Also parts of the form must be missing, such as `competition` and `switch_competition` (inputs).

Comment: I was calling three times the template method to render the view to output an updated view, but I didn't tested if it will work anymore without recall the render method. The `$_SESSION['competition'] = 'Serie A'` is because when an user try to search a matchday when he visit for the first time the page, it will not get any results so I tought to set the session variable. the competition is selected from another select form and it's not mandatory due to the fact that a default competition is already setted. `switch_competition` is the submit button.

Comment: But that last part of your code is not only executed when he/she visits the page for the first time, but every time. It's outside of a conditional expression or anything so it will get executed no matter what.

Comment: I was thinking just the same, but the last part of the code is the default code to be executed when an user visit for the first time the page. I need to fix it to load a default league and to switch between the competitions if the user select a different one from the select box.